# Change ToolTipText display duration

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I need to show the tooltips over a datagridview cell and that is currently achived using the tooltiptext of the datagridview cell property.

I just need to increase the default duration of time that is tooltip is visible any quick ideas please

Comment: A C# example of manipulating the Tool Tip for a DataGridView can be found at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7205385/how-do-i-set-the-autopopdelay-for-a-tooltip-in-a-datagridview-cell

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do this, you need to set the `ShowCellToolTips` property of your DataGridView to `false`, and rather use a standard tooltip control, controlled using the `CellMouseEnter` event of the DataGridView. You can then set the `AutoPopDelay` property of the tooltip to the number of milliseconds that you wish the tool tip window to show for.

Further details and VB.Net sample code for using a standard ToolTip control with a DataGridView can be found [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vblanguage/thread/1cfb0dcf-b756-4c4e-ba3c-6979bf3a33a6).