# How do I set the autoPopDelay for a tooltip in a DataGridView Cell?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a dataGridView that I programatically create where I want to set the toolTipText differently for each row by setting the toolTipText in the first column/cell of each row.  I know I can do that by doing the following:

```
myDataGridView.Rows(n).Cells(0).ToolTipText = varContainingText
```

This works fine.  However, it only displays for the default period of time (5 seconds I believe).  I'd like to set the autoPopDelay but can't seem to figure out how.  I can't seem to do something like:

```
myDataGridView.Rows(n).Cells(0).autoPopDelay = 10000
```

This is not a valid reference.  How do I set the autoPopDelay for this?

Answer (score 3):

You should use a separate ToolTip for the DataGridView and use the CellMouseEnter event to set the text for the cell. DataGridView.ShowCellToolTips should be set to False.

```
ToolTip toolTip1 = new ToolTip();
//....
private void dgv_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
toolTip1.AutomaticDelay = 100; 
toolTip1.AutoPopDelay= 1000; 
toolTip1.ReshowDelay = 100; 
dgv.ShowCellToolTips = false; 
} 

void dgv_CellMouseEnter(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) 
{ 
    toolTip1.SetToolTip(dgv, dgv[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString()); 
}
```