# Datagridview Cell ToolTip Delay Time

Tags: c#, datagridview, tooltip

I have a DataGridView that shows student's points for each lesson and at some point I should show some information about the point via Tooltip. What I want is when user enters a specific cell, after 2 seconds ToolTip will appear at current cell, will be shown 2 seconds time and shows information about the point. I used that code:

```
    private void dgwPNotlar_CellMouseEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        var hucre = dgwPNotlar.CurrentCell;
        var hucre_loc = dgwPNotlar.GetCellDisplayRectangle(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex, false);

        toolTip1.Show("//Info&" + e.ColumnIndex.ToString() + "&" + e.RowIndex.ToString(), dgwPNotlar, hucre_loc.X, hucre_loc.Y);
    }
```

I set AutomaticDelay 500, AutoPopDelay 2000, InitialDelay 2000 and Reshow Delay 2000 for ToolTip. But ToolTip comes immediately when I enter a Datagridview cell and does not vanish. When I check my code, I saw this method was called several times although mouse stays still in the cell.

What can I do?

Comment: Please Refer Following URLs

[Stackoverflow][1]

[Stackoverflow][2]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5718141/how-to-override-default-tooltip-behavior-of-a-c-sharp-datagridview-to-increase-t
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7205385/how-do-i-set-the-autopopdelay-for-a-tooltip-in-a-datagridview-cell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of that "Auto" stuff is irrelevant if the `ToolTip` is not being displayed automatically.  You're showing it manually so there's no delay.  If you want a delay then you need to use a `Timer`.

If you want a delay of 2 seconds then `Start` a `Timer` with an `Interval` of 2000 and `Show` to `ToolTip` in the `Tick` event handler.  You can handle the `CellMouseLeave` event of the grid too and `Stop` the `Timer` there, thus cancelling the tip before it's shown if the user leaves that cell before the delay's up.

Comment: can you give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

I found why DataGridView_CellEnter event called several times. When Tooltip shows up over the cell (location based on cell rectangular) mouse pointer stays over ToolTip and the point tracker plies the cell overlay and Tooltip overlay. That makes CellEnter and CellLeave methots called several times.

Thanks all.